# Constructor is not inherited even using `using`

Tags: inheritance, c++11

I'm wondering why the following code does not compile. This is only a showcase example, I'm not arguing about the inheritance of standard containers etc.

```
class A : public std::array<int,3>
{
public:
    using std::array<int,3>::array;

    // define other methods (no data members)
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {        
    A a ({1,2,3});      
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (g++) complains because it can only find the default constructor `A()`, eventhough I think I did what needed be to inherit the constructors from `std::array`.

Would someone please care to explain why it acts so and how I could cope with that problem without redefining and forwarding by hand the implicit constructor(s)?

Of course the code

```
using A = std::array<int,3>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {        
    A a ({1,2,3});      
    return 0;
}
```

compiles fine, but I need to add some home-made operators to fit my purposes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have constructors; it's an aggregate. Trying to inherit them is probably a bad idea. Trying to inherit `std::array` at all is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Constructors are not inherited, they cannot be. It is more like a delegate with this syntax.

Comment: @Sebastian: ouch, my bad. I forgot about that one. And, yeah, inheriting std::array is bad. I'll go to hell, then ;)

Comment: @luk32: I know that, I'd just like the compiler to do the job for me as in other cases. But I guess Sebastian comment explains a lot...

Comment: @luk32 c++11 allow constructor inheritance even if here it is not a solution : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Object_construction_improvement

Comment: @galop1n Ok, fair enough if it's named like that. But this is not real inheritance, it is still more like delegation. It is like a lifting the functions into the name scope of the derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::array` do not have constructors except the automatic ones to keep it an aggregate and having a base class is a rejection of the aggregate initialization rules as explain here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Answer (score 0):

The braced list you provided to the constructor is considered as one parameter. The compiler is looking for a constructor with one parameter of class A. This parameter must be able to accept a braced list of 3 integers for it to be used. Since there's no such constructor for class A the compiler issues an error.

Comment: Obviously yes, but the fact is that I tried to inherit the aggregation mechanism, which is not possible. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: In any case, in the code you showed here, a constructor with 1 parameter is searched. Even if it was a perfectly legal aggregate, the syntax you used would search for a constructor with one parameter and not perform aggregate initialization. The right syntax would be without the parenthesis (either with or without the equal sign).

Comment: Well, both work for `std::array`, so I expect(ed) the same to work here, is all.